# Sync chef's cookbooks on self-host gitlab

Tags: configuration, chef-infra, gitlab

The other day i was looking if it is possible to sync my chef workstation/server for easy manage/visualization of all cookbook components. I already tried looking for one solution and I didn't found any good info about this topic. So my questions are:

- Is it posible to do?
- Is it a good solution? And if not recommend one better?
- If it's viable explain how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Normally cookbooks already live in source control so it's not really a normal request. You can use the `knife download` command to pull back cookbook data but probably not in a format you want. tl;dr go the other direction, git -> chef server.

Comment: What I wanted to know is: Can I change the chef source control by gitlab (or other) and if i can, how?

Comment: Chef doesn’t use source control, you have to specifically upload things in to Chef Server. Source control is your own business, not Chef’s.

Comment: Yes but what if i make workstation push cookbooks on gitlab and the chef server sync them so I could control all from gitlab. Is this solution viable? And if you can, explain me the way you do it. (I'm new working with chef so i don't know what i can and what i can't do)

Comment: You would use GitLab CI (or Jenkins, or whatever) with a job like `knife upload /`. Depends on your exact workflow, that doesn't generally work safely for cookbooks, but is fine for non-cookbook objects like roles and environments.

Comment: I'm grateful for info but it didn't solved completely my original question.

Comment: Then you need to better explain your question.